# Replace PHP nested/multidimensional array's numeric key with a string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have an array like this - which is generated through a dynamic if/while loop via Wordpress

```
<?php $qry = new WP_Query($args); if ($qry->have_posts()) : 
$count = 0; 
$arr = array(); 
while ($qry->have_posts()) : $qry->the_post(); $count++;
$thetitle = get_the_title();
$arr[$count] = array("name" => $thetitle);?>
<?php if( have_rows('product_attributes') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('product_attributes') ): the_row();  ?>
<?php array_push($arr[$count], get_sub_field('text'));?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>     
<?php endwhile; endif ?>
<?php print_r($arr); ?>
```

Result

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => Breakfast Cereal [0] => 92.50% [1] => 11.00% [2] => 14.0 MJ/kg [3] => 10.00% [4] => 7.50% [5] => 1.80% ) )
```

After using `<?php $json_out = json_encode(array_values($arr)); ?>` to convert to json and remove the key for the array.

```
<?php $json_out = json_encode(array_values($arr)); ?>
<?php echo $json_out; ?>`
```

Result

```
[{"name":"Breakfast Cereal","0":"92.50%","1":"11.00%","2":"14.0 MJ\/kg","3":"10.00%","4":"7.50%","5":"1.80%"}]
```

How do I replace the numeric keys in the nested array with strings - these strings will be `get_sub_field('title')`

Comment: Try passing [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-force-object) as the second parameter to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sJson = '[{"name":"Breakfast Cereal","0":"92.50%","1":"11.00%","2":"14.0 MJ\/kg","3":"10.00%","4":"7.50%","5":"1.80%"}]';
$aNamesForKeys = [0 => "Some", 1 => "Random", 2 => "Name"];
$aData = get_object_vars(json_decode($sJson)[0]);

foreach ($aData as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($aNamesForKeys[$key])) {
        $aData[$aNamesForKeys[$key]] = $value;
        unset($aData[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($aData);
```

**Output**

```
array(7) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "Breakfast Cereal"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "10.00%"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "7.50%"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "1.80%"
  ["Some"]=>
  string(6) "92.50%"
  ["Random"]=>
  string(6) "11.00%"
  ["Name"]=>
  string(10) "14.0 MJ/kg"
}
```

Take care of possible key collisions!

Comment: $oData = (object) $aData;
In case you need an object.